# Change div content by clicking a word/link with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am basically trying to have a word (page 2) be clickable and act as a link to display different div content.  When they select option 2, then click the next button, they should be able to click "Page 2" test and cause that to display the id="test1" (Choice 1, Page 1) content.  I have tried a few  variables but haven't been able to get any to work.  The best I could do is get it to take you back to the choice options, but I'd like to eliminate any users error and just go straight to the first page of the choice they should have made.
Any help would be grateful. And sorry, JQuery is not an option.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<center>
<head>
<title>Test2</title>
<script>
function formReset()
{
    document.getElementById("home").innerHTML ="";
    document.getElementById("main").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("1").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("2").checked = false;
}
function nextPage()
{
    if (document.getElementById("1").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("main").style.display = 'none';
        }
        else
    if (document.getElementById("2").checked == true){
        document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("main").style.display = 'none';
        }
    return true;
}
function otherPage()
{
    switch (document.getElementById('home').innerHTML)
    {
        case document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML:
            (document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = document.getElementById("choice2_page2").innerHTML)
            break;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>This is a test of the radio buttons</h1>
 <br />
 <div>
<form>
    <div id="home"></div>
    <div id="main">
    <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="1">1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="grp1" id="2">2<br>
    <br />
    <input type="button" name="button" value="Next" onClick="nextPage()">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div name="test1" id="test1" style="display:none"><!-- Display this content -->
  <h2>Choice 1<br>Page 1</h2>
  <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset_form" onClick="formReset()">
</div>
<div name="test2" id="test2" style="display:none">
  <h2>Choice 2<br>Page 1</h2>
  <input type="button" value="Next" id="page_choice" onclick="otherPage()">
  <input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset_form" onClick="formReset()">
</div>
<div name="choice2_page2" id="choice2_page2" style="display:none">
<h2>You should have chose<br><b>Choice 1</b></h2><!-- When clicked, this "Choice 1" should display the contents of id="test1" (Choice 1, Page 1)-->
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset_form" onClick="formReset()">
</div>
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you may be looking for

```
function showPage(id)
{
     document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}

<a href="javascript:showPage('test1');">Choice 1</a>
```

Comment: It will display the content I am looking but the old content is still displayed as well.  I can work with that though, thank you much.

Comment: I added document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = ""; to the function and that clears out the old content.  When I refresh and go back to the main page though, both contents are displayed.  I'll keep working it.

Comment: Added document.getElementById("test1").innerHTML =""; to the function and it's perfect.

Comment: **correction**  That gave me a blank div when I tried to go through choices again.  document.getElementById("test1").style.display = 'none'; worked better

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think this is what you want, it may be a bit big, but it's a full solution for your problem, I guess. Mainly, you have some pages, the user may choose, which page to see first, but then you force the user to see all next pages one by one till the end. At least, it's what I did here.

You may add as much text pieces (pages) as you like in textContent array, just check that you have a corresponding number of radio buttons.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv" style="text-align: center">
    <div id="textDiv"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv">
        <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radGrp"><label for="rad1">1</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="radGrp"><label for="rad2">2</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="radGrp"><label for="rad3">3</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="radGrp"><label for="rad4">4</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad5" name="radGrp"><label for="rad5">5</label><br>
    </div>
    <div id="btnDiv">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="show"><br>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        /*here we push the onclick attribute in js, so the code is unobtrusive*/
        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){formContent();};

        var radios = document.getElementsByName("radGrp"),
            idCurrent = 0,
            firstRun = true,
            textContent = [
                "<h3>option 1</h3><p>here is the text of option 1 :(</p>",
                "<h3>option 2</h3><p>here is the text of option 2 :)</p>",
                "<h3>option 3</h3><p>here is the text of option 3!</p>",
                "<h3>option 4</h3><p>here is the text of option 4 :-D</p>",
                "<h3>option 5</h3><p>here is the text of option 5 :-P</p>"
            ];

        function hideDivs(){
            document.getElementById("textDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("radioDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("btn").value = "next";
            firstRun = false;
        }

        function restoreDivs(){
            idCurrent=0;
            document.getElementById("textDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("radioDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("btn").value = "show";
            firstRun = true;
        }

        /*function to find the id of a checked radio from the group*/
        function findChecked(){
            for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
                if (radios[i].checked) idCurrent = radios[i].id;
            }

            /*since the id is in text, we cut the first part and leave*/
            /*just the number*/
            idCurrent = parseInt(idCurrent.slice(3));
        }

        /*actual function*/
        function formContent(){
            if (idCurrent == 0) findChecked();
            if (firstRun) {
                hideDivs();
            }
            /*pushing into textDiv values from textContent array, which*/
            /*is your pages content*/
            document.getElementById("textDiv").innerHTML = textContent[idCurrent - 1];
            if (idCurrent<radios.length) {
                idCurrent++;
                /*changing the button value if the current piece of text*/
                /*is the last one*/
            } else if (idCurrent == radios.length) {
                idCurrent++;
                document.getElementById("btn").value = "finish!";
                /*if there is no more text, we just restore everything to*/
                /*the initial state*/
            } else {
                restoreDivs();
                idCurrent = 0;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not exaclty what I was going for but it gives me a little more practice using variables so thatnk you.  It's for a trouble shooting guide for work.  When they have a power issue and they go through all the steps to trouble shoot that, the last step is verifying the device charges.  So I was trying to get it to link to the steps for charging issues rather than having them start over at the choice radios.  Not a big deal, just trying to make it idiot proof.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here I've added consequent steps, that can be split into some categories (here: 3), if you select a step from some category, you will just read it. Hope that helps ;)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="mainDiv" style="text-align: center">
    <div id="textDiv"></div>
    <div id="radioDiv">
        <input type="radio" id="rad1" name="radGrp"><label for="rad1">1. reinstall os (step 1)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad2" name="radGrp"><label for="rad2">2. reinstall os (step 2)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad3" name="radGrp"><label for="rad3">3. reinstall os (step 3)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad4" name="radGrp"><label for="rad4">4. reinstall os (step 4)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad5" name="radGrp"><label for="rad5">5. watering a plant (step 1)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad6" name="radGrp"><label for="rad6">6. watering a plant (step 2)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad7" name="radGrp"><label for="rad7">7. reading alphabet (step 1)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad8" name="radGrp"><label for="rad8">8. reading alphabet (step 2)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad9" name="radGrp"><label for="rad9">9. reading alphabet (step 3)</label><br>
        <input type="radio" id="rad10" name="radGrp"><label for="rad10">10. reading alphabet (step 4)</label><br>
    </div>
    <div id="btnDiv">
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="show"><br>
    </div>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){formContent();};

        var radios = document.getElementsByName("radGrp"),
            idCurrent = 0,
            planCurrent,
            firstRun = true,
            instructions = [
                [0,1,2,3], /* your instruction plans */
                [4,5], /* this is the second plan (with index = 1) and it has steps 5 and 6 */
                [6,7,8,9] /* this is the third plan (with index = 2) and it has steps 7, 9, 9 and 10 */
            ],
            textContent = [
                "<h3>reinstall os (step 1)</h3><p>download .iso from torrent</p>",
                "<h3>reinstall os (step 2)</h3><p>burn it to a cd of usb</p>",
                "<h3>reinstall os (step 3)</h3><p>change bios settings</p>",
                "<h3>reinstall os (step 4)</h3><p>boot, install, enjoy</p>",
                "<h3>watering a plant (step 1)</h3><p>pour some water into a flask</p>",
                "<h3>watering a plant (step 2)</h3><p>water the plant, enjoy</p>",
                "<h3>reading alphabet (step 1)</h3><p>read letter \"a\"</p>",
                "<h3>reading alphabet (step 2)</h3><p>read letter \"b\"</p>",
                "<h3>reading alphabet (step 3)</h3><p>read letter \"c\"</p>",
                "<h3>reading alphabet (step 4)</h3><p>read all the other letters, enjoy</p>"
            ];

        function hideDivs(){
            document.getElementById("textDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("radioDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("btn").value = "next";
            firstRun = false;
        }

        function restoreDivs(){
            document.getElementById("textDiv").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("radioDiv").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("btn").value = "show";
            idCurrent=0;
            firstRun = true;
        }

        /*function to find the id of a checked radio from the group*/
        function findChecked(){
            for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
                if (radios[i].checked) idCurrent = radios[i].id;
            }
            idCurrent = parseInt(idCurrent.slice(3))-1;
        }

        /*find which plan checked id belongs*/
        function findPlan(){
            for (var m=0;m<instructions.length;m++){
                for (var n=0;n<instructions[m].length;n++){
                    if (instructions[m][n] == idCurrent) planCurrent = m;
                }
            }
        }

        /*actual function*/
        function formContent(){
            if (firstRun) {
                findChecked();
                findPlan();
                hideDivs();
            }
            /*pushing into textDiv values from textContent array, which is your pages content*/
            document.getElementById("textDiv").innerHTML = textContent[idCurrent];

            /*check that we read just the current plan*/
            if (idCurrent < instructions[planCurrent][instructions[planCurrent].length - 1]){
                idCurrent++;
            } else if (idCurrent == instructions[planCurrent][instructions[planCurrent].length - 1]) {
                idCurrent++;
                document.getElementById("btn").value = "finish!";
            } else {
                restoreDivs();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or you could just split the categories into different radio groups by their names and use the previous version..